# how to transform contours to filled circles?

Tags: python, opencv, tracking, contour

Is there a chance to transform all the contours found in a frame to a filled circle?

Let me explain, my video has many small objects, and it is hard to detect using Mosse tracking, because my objects change its form. So I had an idea, change all the found contours to  filled circles, it means, convert all this objects found on this image:

[image]

to something like this:

[image]

I am using python and Opencv.

Answer (score 0):

To transform contours in filled circle, a simple approach is like:

1. Get each contour
2. Find the bounding box the contour
3. Find the center of the bounding box, will be the *center* of the circle
4. Find the diagonal of the bounding box, will be the *radius* of the circle
5. Draw a circle with given center and radius.

Below an example (it's C++, but you can easily port to python) on how to code the above steps:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // This will enlarge the circles by a "factor"
    float factor = 2;

    // Find blobs and extract contours
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(img.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    Mat1b res(img.size(), uchar(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Get the bounding box of the contours
        Rect bb = boundingRect(contours[i]);

        // Get the center of the bounding box
        // Will be the center of the circle
        Point center(bb.x + bb.width/2, bb.y + bb.height/2);

        // Get the length of the diagonal of the bounding box.
        // Will be the radius of the circle (eventually multiplied by a factor)
        int radius = sqrt(bb.width*bb.width + bb.height*bb.height) / 2;

        // Draw the circle
        circle(res, center, radius*factor, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Original image

[image]

Result with circles

[image]